# Error in entries per page count

Tags: php

I'm working on a site which has paginated entries and want to output where you are currently, e.g. `Showing 10-18 of 50 results` but am having trouble getting the correct output if there are less entries than the per-page limit.

The site uses ExpressionEngine where the last segment of the URI indicates where you are in the page list, so if the limit is 9 per page, the URI would be `/path/to/page/P9/` when you're on the second page, `P18` page 3 etc.

This is what I have so far:

```
$output        = '';

// the variables below are passed from a template to a plugin which does the processing

$url_segment   = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('url_segment'); // e.g. P9, P18 etc.
$per_page      = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('page_num'); // e.g. 9
$total_entries = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('total'); // e.g. 50

$current_page  = preg_match('/^P+[0-9]+$/', $url_segment) === 1 ? str_replace('P','', $url_segment) +1 : 1;

if ($total_entries == 1) {
    $output .= '1 tour';
} else {
    if ($total_entries <= $per_page){
        $output .= '1 to '.($per_page<=$total_entries ? $total_entries : $per_page);
    } else {
        $output .= $current_page.' to ';
        $output .= $current_page+$per_page-1;
    }
    $output .= ' of '.$total_entries.' tours';
}

return $this->return_data = $output;
```

`if ($total_entries <= $per_page)` doesn't ever seem to evaluate to true, e.g. if page limit is 9 but only three entries, it'll say `1 to 9 of 3 entries`.

I thought it might be because I need to make the variables integers but doing that means the other side of the conditional always evaluates as true so when there are more entries that the per-page limit, the output is always same regardless of which page you're on, e.g. `1 to 14 of 14 entries` on all pages.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($total_entries <= $per_page){
    $output .= '1 to '.($per_page<=$total_entries ? $total_entries : $per_page);
```

On this part, you first check if `$total_entries` is less or equal than `$per_page`, but just after, you check if it's more or equal. Bad logic here (and your second if statement is reversed).

Try this :

```
if ($total_entries <= $per_page){
    $output .= '1 to '.$total_entries;
```

Comment: I think part of my problem is that numeric calculations using variables aren't working correctly. For instance `intval($total_entries / $per_page)+1` gives me `1` whereas if I do `intval(14 / 6)+1` which is what the values of the variables are, I get the correct answer, `3`.

Comment: Try to `var_dump` each variable, that can help you

Comment: Turns out the problem was CMS-specific whereby the value of `$total_entries` when passed to my function would output correctly as a string, but when used in mathematical calculations, always evaluated as 0. :/

Comment: Glad you fix it :)